# How to avoid trailing zeros in pandas dataframe column values while reading data from database?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading data from postgresql DB into pandas dataframe. In one of the columns all values are integer while some are missing. Dataframe while reading is attaching trailing zeros to all the values in the column.

e.g. Original Data

```
SUBJID
1031456
1031457
1031458
```

What I am getting in the Dataframe column is this

```
df['SUBJID'].head()
1031456.0
1031457.0
1031458.0
```

I know I can remove it but there are multiple columns & I never know which column will have this problem. So while reading itself I want to ensure that everything is read as string & without those trailing zeros.

I have already tried with `df = pd.read_sql('q',dtype=str)`. But it's not giving desired output.
Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

try setting the dtype of the column to int then to str.

```py
df['SUBJID'] = df['SUBJID'].astype('int32')
df['SUBJID'] = df['SUBJID'].astype(str)
```

if you want to manually fix the strings, then you can do

```py
df['SUBJID'] = df['SUBJID'].apply(lambda x: x.split(".")[0])
```

This should strip out the "." and everything after it, but make sure you don't use it on columns that contain a `"."` that you need.

Comment: No, this doesn't work, it throws following error - Cannot convert non-finite values to integers.

Comment: seems like your dataset doesn't doesn't all have a value as a number, if you don't have a lot of items (or performance doesn't matter) you can run an `apply` to strip out the decimal, I'll update my answer to contain the code for that

Comment: Yes dataset doesn't have all numbers, so getting converted to float & adding trailing zeros. I know I can remove trailing zeros from specific column but that's not the solution as I can have hundreds of columns in my data & so I never know which column to monitor for trailing zero. Moreover data might actually contain .0, which obviously I wont want to remove. I dont want any loss of information. 
      So only solution is while reading itself pandas should read it as string(& not float) even if there are missing values. I don't know how to force pandas to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer because this is different than the other one.

This happens because your dataset contains empty cells, and since `Int` type doesn't support `NA/NaN` it get casted to float.
One solution would be to fill the `NA/NaN` with 0 then set the type as int like so

```
columns = ['SUBJID'] # you can list the columns you want, or you can run it on the whole dataframe if you want to.
df[columns] = df[columns].fillna(0).astype(int)
# then you can convert to string after converting to int if you need to do so
```

Another would be to have the sql query do the filling for you (which is a bit tedious to write if you ask me).

Note that [pandas.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) doesn't have `dtype` argument anyways.